# Play framework checking if something exists in database with Ebean

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

If I try `find.ref(id)` for something that doesn't exist, I get this exception:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[EntityNotFoundException: Bean not found during lazy load or refresh. id[2] type[class models.Argument]]]
```

Is there a way to avoid this and detect when something does not exist, without using `find.byId`? (`byId` is generally  slower, so I'd prefer not to use it when possible.)

Answer (score 0):

use findRowCount() == 0

document:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/db/ebean/Model.Finder.html#findRowCount%28%29